# Reduce the range of time in sequence analysis with R

Tags: r, range, sequence, traminer, standardized

I have a sequence that happens over a very long period of time. I tried 8 different algorithms to classify my sequences (OM, CHi2,...). Time goes from 1 to 123. I have 110 individual and 8 events.

My results are not as expected. First, it's very difficult to read. Second, a category contains too many representatives sequence (group3). Third, the number of sequence per group is really unbalanced.

It may comes from the fact that my time variable has a range of 123. I searched for articles that had an issue with a too long time range. I read in  Sabherwal and Robey (1993) and in Shi and Prescott (2011) that you can **standardize** "each sequence by dividing the number  of transformations required by the length of the longer sequence". How can I do that in R?

Please find underneath a description of my data:

```
library(TraMineRextras)
head(seq.tse.data)
seq.tse.data <- structure(list(
ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
     4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
     6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
Year = c(2008L, 2010L, 2012L, 2007L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L,
       2013L, 1996L, 1997L, 1999L, 2003L, 2006L, 2008L, 
       2012L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2003L, 2007L, 2007L,
       2009L, 2009L, 2011L, 2014L, 2016L, 2006L, 2009L, 
       2011L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L), 
Event = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,5L, 1L, 5L,
5L,5L,4L,5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,5L,5L,5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L,5L)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L)
      )
    seq.sts <- TSE_to_STS(seq.tse.data,
                     id = 1, timestamp = 2, event = 3, 
                     stm =NULL, tmin = 1935, tmax = 2018,
                     firstState = "None")    
seq.SPS <- seqformat(seq.sts, 1:84, from = "STS", to = "SPS")
seq.obj <- seqdef(seq.SPS)
> head(seq.tse.data)
  ID Year Event
1  1 2008     5
2  2 2010     4
3  2 2012     5
4  3 2007     3
5  3 2009     1
6  3 2010     5
> head(seq.obj)
    Sequence                            
[1] (None,74)-(5,10)-1                  
[2] (None,76)-(4,2)-(5.4,6)-2           
[3] (None,73)-(3,2)-(3.1,1)-(5.3.1,8)-3 
[4] (None,62)-(3,12)-(5.3,4)-(5.3.1,6)-3
[5] (None,73)-(5,11)-1                  
[6] (None,69)-(4,4)-(5.4,11)-2  

> head(alphabet(seq.obj),10)
 [1] "(1,1)"  "(1,10)" "(1,11)" "(1,12)" "(1,14)" "(1,19)" "(1,2)"  "(1,21)" "(1,25)" "(1,3)" 
...
[145] "(5.4.3.1,5)"   "(5.4.3.1,6)"   "(5.4.3.1,7)"   "(5.4.3.1,8)"   "(5.4.3.1.2,9)" "(None,1)"      "(None,11)"     "(None,20)"    
[153] "(None,26)"     "(None,30)"     "(None,38)"     "(None,41)"     "(None,42)"     "(None,44)"     "(None,45)"     "(None,49)"    
[161] "(None,51)"     "(None,53)"     "(None,55)"     "(None,57)"     "(None,58)"     "(None,59)"     "(None,60)"     "(None,61)"    
[169] "(None,62)"     "(None,64)"     "(None,65)"     "(None,66)"     "(None,67)"     "(None,68)"     "(None,69)"     "(None,7)"     
[177] "(None,70)"     "(None,71)"     "(None,72)"     "(None,73)"     "(None,74)"     "(None,75)"     "(None,76)"     "(None,77)"    
[185] "(None,78)"     "(None,79)"
```

Thanks in advance,

Antonin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added commands to recreate the sequence.

Comment: You have too many questions here: standardization of the distances (or do you really want to standardize sequences?), effect of neglecting time, issue with size of alphabet and sequence length. Please post a separate question for each of these issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question and added extra questions on a separate link.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The title refers to 'standardize time', the text to 'standardize a sequence', and the provided reference is about standardizing dissimilarities. Moreover, the outcome provided as links  do not correspond to the provided example data. Also, provide the outcome examples as text instead of links to screenshots.

Comment: I apologize for this lack of accuracy. I guess the article I use is not enough accurate too. I tried to rephrase my question and body of the text. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your question is about normalizing the dissimilarities between sequences. E.g., Sabherwal and Robey (1993, p 557) refer to the distance standardization proposed by Abbott & Hyrcac (1990) and do not consider at all the standardization of a sequence. Anyway, I cannot figure out what the standardization of a sequence could be.

The `seqdist` function of `TraMineR` has a `norm` argument that can be used to  normalize some of the distance measures proposed. Here is an  excerpt from the `seqdist` help page:

> Distances can optionally be normalized by means of the norm argument.
>   If set to "auto", Elzinga's normalization (similarity divided by
>   geometrical mean of the two sequence lengths) is applied to "LCS",
>   "LCP" and "RLCP" distances, while Abbott's normalization (distance
>   divided by length of the longer sequence) is used for "OM", "HAM" and
>   "DHD". Elzinga's method can be forced with "gmean" and Abbott's rule
>   with "maxlength". With "maxdist" the distance is normalized by its
>   maximal possible value. For more details, see Gabadinho et al. (2009,
>   2011). Finally, "YujianBo" is the normalization proposed by Yujian and
>   Bo (2007) that preserves the triangle inequality.

Let me warn you that while normalization makes distances between two short sequences (say of length 10) more comparable with distances between two long sequences (say of length 100), it does not solve the issue of comparing sequences of different lengths.

You find a detailed discussion on the normalization of distance and similarity in sequence analysis in [Elzinga & Studer (2016)](https://lacosa.lives-nccr.ch/sites/lacosa.lives-nccr.ch/files/proc-lacosa2-elzingastuder_paper_35s.pdf).

Comment: Your comments really answer my need. The quote from the article I used (Shi and Prescott, 2011) was unclear. Thank you once again!